# Formula to determine correct offset for wpf resized images

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm running into some problems using WPF to resize images, in that the images are coming out blurry at some resolutions. I'm actually writing these out to files, so `SnapToDevicePixels` won't help (I'm not even in a WPF app, I'm just referencing `System.Windows`).

I understand that this is related to the device independence of pixels in WPF, but I now need to know how I can calculate the offset of the pixels such that I get crisp images.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any need to use WPF? This GDI based code that we use produces excellent resizing powers:

```
    public static Size ResizeImage(
       string fileName, 
       string targetFileName, 
       Size boundingSize, 
       string targetMimeType, 
       long quality)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo imageCodecInfo = 
            ImageCodecInfo
               .GetImageEncoders()
               .Single(i => i.MimeType == targetMimeType);
        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = 
            new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            Image img ;
            try
            {
                img = Image.FromStream(fs, true, true);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                throw new FileFormatException("cannot decode image",ex);
            } 
            using (img)
            {
                double targetAspectRatio = 
                    ((double)boundingSize.Width) / boundingSize.Height;
                double srcAspectRatio = ((double)img.Width) / img.Height;
                int targetWidth = boundingSize.Width;
                int targetHeight = boundingSize.Height;
                if (srcAspectRatio > targetAspectRatio)
                {
                    double h = targetWidth / srcAspectRatio;
                    targetHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(h));
                }
                else
                {
                    double w = targetHeight * srcAspectRatio;
                    targetWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(w));
                }
                using (Image thumbNail = new Bitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight))
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(thumbNail))
                {
                    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    Rectangle rect = 
                        new Rectangle(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);
                    g.DrawImage(img, rect);
                    thumbNail.Save(
                        targetFileName, imageCodecInfo, encoderParams);
                }
                return new Size(targetWidth, targetHeight);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: GDI is the fallback, but we encountered problems which required a lot of locking to get around in the past, and according to the labels on the box, WPF is supposed to be faster for this kind of thing. We've already been using WPF for awhile, and have hit most of the teething issues we'll see at scale already. It might sound like sunken cost, but this seems like a smallish issue with what I hope will be a straightforward isolated solution, which will mean I don't have to rewrite a large part of an extant solution.